# Are there other Brahmas and universes?

Tags: krishna, scripture, brahma, creation

Lord Brahma is said to be the creator of Earth but what about other planets? Who created them?

I have heard that for every planet there is a creator like Brahma.

I have also seen an incident in Shri Krishna when Lord Brahma feels that no one is more powerful than him and abducts friends of Shri Krishna (*in child hood*).

Then as a lesson, Shri Krishna summons all Brahmas (*creator of other planets*) to teach a lesson to Lord Brahma that he is not the only one creator

Is there any explanation about this?

PS: The story resembles in this
[**link**](http://www.kasarabada.org/bhagavatam%2015.html) but this did not mention about the other Brahmas.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[**Chapter III On seeing the Devî**](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk03ch03.htm) **of Devi Bhagavatam** says, there are multiple Brahmas, multiple Vishnus and multiple Rudras.

After killing Dânavas Madhu Kaitabha, three deities got into a beautiful Vimana sent by Devi Bhagavathi. They saw multiple Satyaloka, multiple Vishnuloka and multiple Kailasa.

Brahma said this to his son Narada,

> Then the car, where we were situated, began to get up high in the sky,
> and in the twinkling of an eye, we reached Brahmâ loka, that is
> saluted by all the Devas. **There S'ambhu and Kes'ava were greatly
> bewildered to see Brahmâ of that place**. In the council hall of Brahmâ,
> the Vedas with their Angas, the serpents, hills, oceans and rivers
> were seen. Seeing all these, Visnu and Mahes'vara asked me :-- **“O
> Four-faced one! Who is this eternal Brahmâ?** I replied :-- I do not
> know who is this Brahmâ? Who am I? and who is He? why has this error
> come over me? You, too, also are gods so you can better ponder over
> it.” Next our car, going with the swiftness of mind went, in the
> twinkling of an eye, to the beautiful all auspicious Kailâs'a mountain
> surrounded by bliss-giving Yaksas. It was beautified by the Mandâra
> garden, resonated by the sweet cooings of S'ukas and cuckoos and the
> sweet sounds of lutes and small drums and tabors. **When we reached
> there we saw the five faced, three-eyed Bhagavân S'ashi S'ekhara, with
> ten hands, wearing tiger skin, and the upper garment of the elephant
> skin**. He was then, getting out of his abode, riding on a bull. His two
> sons, the great heroes, Ganes'a and Kârtikeya, beautifully adorned,
> were attending Him as His body guards. Nandi and all other hosts were
> following Him, chanting victories to Him. O Muni Narâda! we were
> greatly wondered to see another S'ankara, surrounded by the Matrikâs.
> So much so, that perplexed with doubts, I sat down there. Next our
> aeroplane went on with the force of wind; and in an instant reached
> the abode of Vaikuntha, the amusement court of Laksmî. O Sûta! There
> at Vaikuntha, **we saw a wonderful manifestation of power. Our companion
> Visnu was greatly surprised to see that excellent city. We saw there
> four-armed Visnu, of the colour of Âtasi flower, wearing yellow
> garments, adorned with divine ornaments sitting on Garuda**. Laksmî Devî
> is fanning wonderful chowry to Him. Struck with wonder at the sight of
> the eternal Visnu, we took our seat on the car and looked at one
> another's face.

Besides this, "**Concept of multiple Brahmandas**" is described in [Chapter 10 "Shiva Swallowing Poison" of Skanda Purana](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/25324/44f_chapter_10_1.pdf) (Pg- 78).

This chapter says

> He (Ganesha) saw crores of spherical Cosmic Eggs like so many atoms.
> They were getting merged and dissolved in Mahesha who was in linga
> form.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, there are as many Brahmas and Rudras as there are universes:

> *ananta brahmāṇḍera yata brahmā-rudra-gaṇa
>
>   cira-loka-pāla-śabde tāhāra gaṇana* [CC - 2.21.58]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Actually it is very difficult to ascertain the number of universes. Every universe has its separate Lord Brahmā and Lord Rudra, who are known as permanent governors. Therefore there is also no counting them.

There is another account regarding this where Krishna ask his door keeper which Brahma has come to visit Him. Brahma surprised by this question of the door keeper later asks Krishna:

> Why did you inquire which Brahmā had come to see You? What is the
>   purpose of such an inquiry? Is there any other Brahmā besides me
>   within this universe? [CC - 2.21.65]

Krishna smiled hearing this and called upon other Brahmas and unlimited Brahmas arrived there:

> These Brahmās had different numbers of heads. Some had ten heads, some
>   twenty, some a hundred, some a thousand, some ten thousand, some a
>   hundred thousand, some ten million and others a hundred million. No
>   one can count the number of faces they had. [CC - 2.21.67]

So in short, **yes there are other Brahmas**.

**REFERENCE:** [Chaitanya Charitamruta](http://vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/21)

Comment: [Just curious] So, Lord Vishnu is only single all over the Universe?

Comment: @Mr_Green unfortunately no! As per that scripture, only Krishna is single. In Krishnaism, Krishna is considered as the supreme Brahma and from Him all other partial incarnations (Vishnu, Mahavishnu, Khirodkshayi Vishnu, etc.) arise.

Comment: strange, that is confusing..

Comment: @Mr_Green hmm, but that's actually logical as we know there can be many universes.

Comment: @jabahar The Chaitanya Charitamrita is a controversial thing to quote from, since its authority is pretty much only accepted by Gaudiya Vaishnavas.  Is the stuff about multiple Brahmas in any more generally accepted scriptures?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan not all of CC can be considered controversial. I knew about this incident regarding multiple Brahmas, so quoted. I'll see if it's present in other scriptures. Nevertheless, the words of a saint like Chaitanya Mahaprabhu is certainly more valid and acceptable than other stories and incidents present on the Internet.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan also, I believe because Chaitanya Mahaprabhu  told this, we will find no scriptures that'll say otherwise. Even though we may not find any statement that says there are multiple Brahmas in different universes, we'll certainly not find any statement that'll say ours is the only universe that there is and our Brahma is the only Brahma that exists. Still, I'll try to find.

Comment: @jabahar Yes, the words of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu certainly carry more weight than the sort of internet links that a lot of people are using on this site.  And you're right, even for those who don't accept Chaitanya's divinity, he was still someone who was extremely well-versed in scriptures, so his words are a good indication of what is there in scriptures.

Comment: Yes, there a multiple andas, each with a Brahma/Shiva/Indra etc. There is karya-vaikuntam for each andam, where devas go to pray to Vishnu for help from demons. Source upanyasam by velukkudi & krishnapremi swamis, and this verse denoting Vishnu - akhila-anda-koti-brahma-anda-nayaka

Comment: This is not a valid reference.

Answer (score 5):

Bhagavatha says there are innumerable universes contained in spherical shell, separated by layers of elemental matters. Region within this called brahmanda or brahma egg.

If you compare the size of brahmanda to that of modern day size of our milkyway galaxy, it would be roughly about 1/10 the size of milkyway galaxy. Brahmanda is surrounded by 7 spherical layers of elemental matter with each being 10 times thick as one preceding it.

Each brahmanda has its own brahma, vishnu , shiva, the creator, sustainer, destroyer. These are the three aspects present in all other innumerable universes.

Then comes the question, what exactly controls all these innumerable brahmandas. The superior force which permeates innumerable brahmandas are called mahavishnu. It is also called as absolute eternal para-brahman in purusha sookta.

Fifth canto of [bhagavata](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5) describes all the thing, I said above.

Answer (score 4):

First you should understand one thing is that all stories in Hinduism are mythical and contains hidden meanings. Actually Brahma didn't create this earth, he created the whole world, means all other planets including our earth...

People may confuse with this sloka and assume that there many Brahmas and Shivas....

Śrī Caitanya Caritāmṛta Madhya 21.58

> ananta brahmāṇḍera yata brahmā-rudra-gaṇa
>
> cirloka-pāla-śabde tāhāra gaṇana

SYNONYMS

> ananta — unlimited; brahmāṇḍera — of the universes; yata — all; brahmā — Lord Brahmās; rudra-gaṇa — and Lord Śivas; cira-loka-pāla — permanent governors of the worlds; śabde — by the word; tāhāra — of them; gaṇana — counting.

TRANSLATION

> "Actually it is very difficult to ascertain the number of universes. Every universe has its separate Lord Brahmā and Lord Śiva, who are known as permanent governors. Therefore there is also no counting them.

But we go through the detailed meaning the purpote is,

Lord Brahmā and Lord Śiva are called *cira-loka-pāla*, permanent governors. This means that they govern the affairs of the universe from the beginning of the creation to the end. In the next creation, the same living entities may not be present, but because Brahmā and Śiva are existing from the beginning to the end, they are called cira-loka-pāla, permanent governors. Loka-pāla means "predominating deities." There are eight predominating deities of the prominent heavenly planets, and they are Indra, Agni, Yama, Varuṇa, Nirṛti, Vāyu, Kuvera and Śiva.

Comment: Does it mean, He is the creator of all Galaxies in Universe?

Comment: Where is it mentioned that Brahma created all the planets? Please backup your claims. Even your answer looks more like a comment to me.

Comment: Actually this is from my knowledge, but I've seen it in many websites, for example, http://hinduism.about.com/od/godsgoddesses/p/brahma.htm

Comment: @KiranRS I don't think there is anything to be confused about. The translation their clearly states presence of unlimited Brahmas. Anyway, to make things more clear I have added other verses from that chapter in the answer. Hope this will clear the confusions if any.

Comment: Yoga Vashishtha talks about multiple Brahmas

Comment: Many people do not accept this scripture as authentic.

Answer (score 0):

Brahma isn't creator of just one planet's life but of universe. A universe has many planets with life in them but one Brahma is creator of one universe and so there are uncountable universes with Brahmas having upto millions of heads & our universe and Brahma are the smallest with Brahma having 4 heads.

Sources: - Chaitanya Charitamrita ISKCON & upper 2 lines are from reference of Yoga Vasishta that there are many alien planets with life in them & none of them knows about the other. And http://scsmathinternational.com/guidance/2015/150615-SanatanSikha-BrahmasRealm.php

Comment: Hello and welcome to Hinduism.SE. We appreciate your inputs on this but we expect the users to post detailed answer on the site along with relevant references to support your answer. For more information, you can refer [Please answer in detail along with references to support your answers](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/271) meta post.

Comment: yes for this answer i have ISKCON's chaitanya charitamrita as source...next time i will make sure i give the source too:)

Comment: Hey Shivam, you can edit this post to add the sources.

Comment: i took sources as Yoga vasishtha & Chaitanya Charitamrita...& this much was enough for the question so i wrote that much only!:)

Comment: I understand. Please mention the same in your post with detail on at what scenario in that book/scripture this was mentioned. Please go through the meta question which I linked.

Comment: sir is the answer to this question-http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12313/what-are-the-weapons-used-by-indra-other-than-vajra/13677#13677 now valid?

Comment: No Sir. Users here are expecting Expert level answers which are explained in detail. Please check the marked answer. "Make people believe". I hope you will take this positive and try to answer in same way from next time. Cheers :)

Comment: Answers should be backed up with specific citations of sources. (For example, it's not enough to say Chaitanya Charitamrita, you should cite or quote a specific verse or verses.). So I'm deleting your answer for the time being.  If you want to revise your answer to meet the standards of the site, then edit it and flag me to undelete it.

Comment: @ShivamNer No need to take it personal but un-sourced answer do get deleted. It might sound strict but it's required to maintain quality

Comment: ok...fine...i gotta work of structuring my answer properly..yes i got ur point..god bless u bro:)

Comment: This is not a valid reference downvoted.

Comment: Broken link, Please update with correct and link and then flag to remove citation banner

Answer (score -1):

There are infinite universes, since it's impossible for Brahma to rule over them all, he manifests a copy of himself in every universe that's created. Each universe has size & lifespan according to the number of heads of the Brahma in it. Our Brahma has 4 heads so ours is the smallest kind of universe available.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to HSE. Though your answer sounds great, we are strict about proper citations from scriptures. Please provide necessary citations from online sources.