# Which Hindu scriptures talk about multiple universes or planets?

Tags: vashishta, science, yoga-vashishtha

The universe is split up into many island-universes, as
described in the [Yoga Vashishtha 6.2.60](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Ttlg-vUmi-4C&pg=PA545&dq=I%20saw%20countless%20creations%20though%20they%20did%20not%20know%20of%20one%20an-%20other%E2%80%99s%20existence&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif1-HL8urMAhXFMI8KHX12C-MQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=I%20saw%20countless%20creations%20though%20they%20did%20not%20know%20of%20one%20an-%20other%E2%80%99s%20existence&f=false)

> I saw countless creations though they did not know of one another’s
>   existence. Some were coming into being, others were perishing, all
>   of them had different shielding atmospheres (from five to thirty-six
>   atmospheres). There were different elements in each, they were
>   inhabited by different types of beings in different stages of
>   evolution.. [In] some there was apparent natural order in others there
>   was utter disorder, in some there was no light and hence no
>   time-sense.

I imagine this is talking about various planets in different stages of evolution.

Are there similar accounts in other Hindu scriptures?

Comment: There are also other verses in Yoga Vasista which talk about Multiverse and  other Planets.

Answer (score 6):

There  is a Shloka in  **Shreemad Bhagvat Purana** mentationing the concept of Multiverse OR Parallel Universes.

> पुरुषोऽण्डं विनिर्भिद्य यदासौ स विनिर्गतः ।
>   आत्मनोऽयनमन्विच्छन्नपोऽस्राक्षीच्छुचिः शुचीः ॥10॥
>
> puruṣo ’ṇḍaṁ vinirbhidya  yadāsau sa vinirgataḥ 
> ātmano ’yanam
>   anvicchann  apo ’srākṣīc chuciḥ śucīḥ
>
> **After separating the different universes,** the gigantic universal form of the Lord [Mahā-Viṣṇu], which came out of the Causal Ocean, the
>   place of appearance for the first puruṣa-avatāra, entered into each of
>   the separate universes, desiring to lie on the created transcendental
>   water [Garbhodaka].[**SB 2.10.10**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/10/10)
>
> ---

Similarly there is another shloka in Bhagvtama – Skanda 6 –Chapter 16 –shloka 37

> क्षित्यादिभिरेष किलावृतः सप्तभिर्दशगुणोत्तरैरण्डकोशः ।
>  यत्र
>   पतत्यणुकल्पः सहाण्डकोटिकोटिभिस्तदनन्तः ॥37॥>br>
>
> kṣity-ādibhir eṣa kilāvṛtaḥ saptabhir daśa-guṇottarair
>   aṇḍa-kośaḥ
>  yatra pataty aṇu-kalpaḥ sahāṇḍa-koṭi-koṭibhis
>   tad anantaḥ
>
> Every universe is covered by seven layers — earth, water, fire, air,
>   sky, the total energy and false ego — each ten times greater than the
>   previous one. T**here are innumerable universes besides this one, and
>   although they are unlimitedly large,** they move about like atoms in
>   You. Therefore You are called unlimited [ananta].[**SB 6.16.37**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/16/37)

Answer (score 3):

Yes they do exist. One example is in Devi Bhagavatam, Tritiya Skandha which describes the story of Brahma, Vishnu and Siva visiting Sridevi. On the way, they watch many Vishnus, Indras, Brahmas and Sivas and many other Brahmandas. That is why Lalita Sahasranama calls her Aneka Koti Brahmanda Janani Divya Vigraha.

The other example is in Skanda MahaPurana Kedara Khanda Chapter 10 Sloka 43 says

dadarśa pretatulyāni liṃgaśaktyātmikāni caḥ brahmāṇḍagoḻakānyeva koṭiśaḥ paramāṇuvat ।

brahmāṇḍagoḻakānyeva koṭiśaḥ paramāṇuvat meaning crores of atom sized Brahmandas

Comment: Your answer is exactly same as my answer posted [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9329/3500).

Answer (score 0):

Yes...we use this phrase-Ananta koti brahmanda nayaka=uncountable crores of universes's lord...there r uncountable numbers of universes & our universe size is the smallest size universe with brahma having 4 heads...there r universes with millions of heads brahma!all universes r bubbles formed from skin pores of Karanodakshayi Vishnu...& story of that bubble which forms an egg is same like chinese pangu story...that egg is silent for 1000 yrs & then it breaks & a man appears in it who is brahma & forms the universe then after 1st day(kalpa)universe get filled with water & there appears garbhodakshayi vishnu on who's navel lotus brahma resides till the end..so in day water level is 1/2 of universe egg & in pralaya it is full...same similarity u will find in all other famous religion's cosmology...:)

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: can u pls give me some time to find that link where i read this..it was like 3 yrs ago..i also written blog so for that i found that link where it was & yes it is right like scriptures will support it so not just imagination of some 1...pls give me some time...sorry!