# What verses talk about other universes in the Puranas?

Tags: scripture, puranas, philosophy, manuscripts

Which verses in the Puranas talk about countless other universes?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12268/which-hindu-scriptures-talk-about-multiple-universes-or-planets?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I have read in Devi bhagavatam . you can refers for it

Comment: Thank you, is that picture what the scriptures mean by universes being bubbles or enclosed units that float around in a void?

Comment: Instead of using the image its better to post texts from the relevant chapter.

Comment: To better understand I kept image