# Can one teleport to another Earth?

Tags: brahma, universe

The scriptures state that there are an infinite number of Brahmas, and an infinite number of universes that have their own planetary systems.

Can one go to another from this earth?

Comment: Scientists are trying in their research

Comment: Yes , through siddhis like Manojava. A siddha can go anywhere he wish.

Comment: Apart from yoga vasistha, which scripture talks of other universes? Can you throw some light?

Comment: @LazyLubber https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/593/are-there-other-brahmas-and-universes?rq=1