# Is anything possible according to vedanta?

Tags: scripture, vedanta, science

In the universe we are living in, there are many scientific facts. Since science is always evolving and is also particular to the time and place, there is no guarantee that the scientific facts will be valid forever and everywhere. One can say that scientific facts are valid at a particular time and/or a particular space. And also science does not deal with the laws of other universes and the phenomenon it cannot observe.

According to the scriptures of sanathan dharma, there are [countless universes](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/593/are-there-other-brahmas-and-universes). Each universe can have entirely different laws, phenomenons and other entities.

Do any scriptures of Vedanta Sastra explicitly tell that any phenomenon is possible?

I mean do Vedanta Sastras tell us that it is possible that a fact we are believing can be false and a contradiction that we believe can be true at some space at some time.

Comment: If you believe Krishna lifted Govardhana, it defies any known laws of 'science' - although to be fair, science doesn't yet deal with Prana Shakti. If you think about Ashta-Maha-Siddhi (being able to levitate is one of them), it defies the laws of 'gravity'.

Answer (score 2):

> Since science is always evolving and is also particular to the time
> and place, there is no guarantee that the scientific facts will be
> valid forever and everywhere. **One can say that scientific facts are valid at a particular time and/or a particular space**.

The fundamental laws of universe doesn't evolve it is always constant, our understanding changes. First we thought atom cannot be split, now we think it can be split, The laws of Universe doesn't change, it is our understanding that changes. **If you call this understanding as Science**, then ofcourse it changes as our understanding and logic is limited and flawed.

---

This question does not properly differentiate between our understanding of universe vs the very laws of the universe and seems to confuse one for another. So I'm answering keeping both in mind.

The question asks

> I mean do Vedanta Sastras tell us that it is possible that a fact we
> are believing can be false and a contradiction that we believe can be
> true at some space at some time.

Well it depends on which philosophy you are asking. If you ask an Advaithi what ever you are believing now, will become false when you realise.

But if you ask a Dvaithi or Vishistadvaiti, then he will say no, the laws we believe, as per the Vedas cannot change as **unlike modern science as Vedic knowledge is not subject to change as Vedas are eternal**.

Modern science may change, but Vedic science, when correctly interpreted, can never change according to Hinduism as Vedas are eternal and apaurusheya, they remain constant and do not change.

But everyone agrees that the basic physical rule of the Universe (or Maya for Advaitins), is always the same, it may have different expressions.

> कस्मिन्नु भगवो विज्ञाते सर्वमिदं विज्ञातं भवतीति ॥ ३ ॥
>
> Sir, what is that through which, if it is known, everything else
> becomes known?
>
> — Mundaka Upanishad, 1.1.3

This verse can be interpreted multiple ways, but it is true that there is a thing if known you'll know everything. **There is a basic dharma of existence which is the basic formula of the existence itself. Nothing other than this can happen.**

Minor variations can happen in the expression of the rule, as some Universes are big, some are small etc., but the basic of it all remains the same. **So our understanding can change but the Universe itself will not change**. In terms of fundamental Dharma, what is possible today, was possible yesterday and will be possible tomorrow. What is not possible remains so. So the Dharma of the Universe stays constant.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137581/discussion-on-answer-by-optimus-is-anything-possible-according-to-vedanta).