# Are there universes without any deities?

Tags: scripture, gods, manuscripts

As per Section III. Utpatti Prakaranam - chapter 29-30:

> Of those countless universes, O Rama, in some there are only plants; some have Brahma, Vishnu, Rudra and others as the presiding deities, ***and some have none at all***.

So are there universes without any deities? Are there any other verses in scriptures that say about such universes?

Comment: Since I had short discussion with this user in some other question and guessing what he is intended to ask, i provided the answer. I guess that he is asking for more mentions or reasons for such existence.

Comment: Hello, Orionuxe, I edited your question. You can rollback incase if it is not in accord with your intention.

Comment: Please mention exact verse number and chapter.

Comment: @hanugm No worries, I appreciate it, sorry if I'm asking about multiverse a lot, it's a part of Hinduism that really fascinates me and I want to know more about it

Comment: @Orionixe no issue... I too feel that fewer questions are there... Yoga Vasista is the scripture you need to study then...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is quite possible that universes can exist without presiding deities. But it should be noted that there is no universe without Parabrahman.

Any universe undergoes three states: creation, preservation and dissolution. Technically, universe is a result of creation. Universe does not exist during dissolution. It is apt to use the word *creation* rather than universe.

Each creation may have different conditions in almost all aspects. All creations may not be same like the universe we are living in. The only entity that remains same in all universes is Parabrahman. All the remaining aspects can vary.

In the same scripture [Yoga Vasishta](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-sanskrit), Bhusunda enumerates various types of creations he remembered. He saw large number of creations and told to Vasishta about some creations among them, which he remember. They are covered in two sections: [section 21](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118565.html) and [section 22](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118566.html) of Nirvana prakarana.

Some verses that are related to the question are as follows.

> I remember the creation of one sole body named Virat in this world,
> when it was entirely devoid of men and asuras in it
>
> [Verse 42]
>
> I remember the sphere of heaven shrouded under a sheet of darkness,
> and when there was no Indra nor king to rule in heaven or earth, which
> had not yet its high and low and middle classes of men.
>
> [Verse 46]

Some verses are saying about the entire creation and some other are saying about conditions at some particular intervals of times in existing creations. Likewise, the initial conditions, later positions and other aspects of all creations may be entirely different.

Comment: So if a universe (creation) does not have Parabrahman it cannot survive?

Comment: @Orionixe Parabrahman is the one who creates in the first place. It does not get created.

Comment: If there are no deities in it the universe is most likely empty with nothing taking place in it.

Comment: One last question, deities in other universes, are they alternate versions of deities from this universe or deities that aren't from this universe or both?

Comment: @Orionixe Most are them can be different.

Comment: @hanugm Different?

Comment: @Orionixe yeah...

Comment: @Orionixe you can read it https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/593/are-there-other-brahmas-and-universes

Comment: Oh I knew about countless other Brahma's in other universes lol