# Can there be multiple Brahman or supreme God in multi verse or other universes?

Tags: brahman, universe

Since we know there are [multiple universes](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/593/22556)

According to the above answers (to the question) there are multiple *Trimurtis* (Brahmã, Visñú, Shiva) so **can there be multiple Brahman as well**.

Comment: You need to re-learn the concept of Brahman (ब्रह्मन्) , it's not only a universal consciousness, it's everything that is or that's not. Everything imaginable or unimaginable is that. Brahman represents the multi - faceted, multi-dimensional, encompassing all the Universes, Multiverse, etc,. **Brahman (ब्रह्मन्) is an OMNIVERSAL all encompassing consciousness and/or reality**. It's the only reality. Everything it is and not *(neti neti)*.

Comment: @Vivikta can you answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing other than Brahman.

**Atma Bodha verse 9**

> All the manifested worlds of things and beings are projected upon the
> substratum which is the Brahman, whose nature is Sat-Chit. This is
> just as the different ornaments are all made out of the same gold
> [though it appears in various forms such as ring, bracelet etc.)

**verse 41**

There are no distinctions in Brahman.